How to Web Scrape Web Page Where Server is Replying to Get Request With Sort-of Redirected Post Request
I am attempting to write a python script to perform some simple web scraping, but I am stumped by how to process (and understand) what the web server is passing me.  When viewing the network traffic when submitting the get request in a browser, I see the server provides a 200 response and then the browser automatically sends a subsequent post request to the same server with the response having the data I am hoping to scrape.
Here is the URL which is entered into a browser results in a final web page with the data to scrape: https://www.defensetravel.dod.mil/neorates/report/index.php?report=oha&locode=AS001&locode2=&rank=13&depend=YES&year=2025&month=01&day=01
Below is the traffic as shown in a browser plug-in.

Below are the details of the final post request the browser is sending:


When I submit a get request, I see the returned content from the server says "You are being redirected ...":
import requests
from requests import Request, Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

urlString = 'https://www.defensetravel.dod.mil/neorates/report/index.php?report=oha&locode=AS001&locode2=&rank=13&depend=YES&year=2025&month=01&day=01'

# Making a GET request
r1 = session.get(urlString, allow_redirects=True)

print(r1.history);
    
soup_r1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup_r1.prettify())

I have also tried to fabricate the post request based on what I saw in the browser plugin, but the server complains with a "The input you provided is not valid".
r3_url = "https://www.defensetravel.dod.mil/neorates/report/index.php";
r3_data = {"day": "01",
          "depend": "YES",
          "locode": "AS001",
          "locode2": "",    
          "month": "01",
          "rank": "13",
          "report": "oha",
          "year": "2025"};
          
r3_header= {"initiator": "https://www.defensetravel.dod.mil",
            "Origin": "https://www.defensetravel.dod.mil",
            "Referer": "https://www.defensetravel.dod.mil/neorates/report/index.php?report=oha&locode=AS001&locode2=&rank=13&depend=YES&year=2025&month=01&day=01",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary34wfzRWc2GjpY1IW",
};

r3 = session.post(r3_url, data=r3_data, headers=r3_header)


soup4 = BeautifulSoup(r3.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup4.prettify())

(Not providing the countless other troubleshooting versions of my code as I attempted to understand what was going on).
I guess at the core, I do not quite understand how the get request (when submitted via a browser) results in the get and a post request.  And more importantly, how does one handle interacting, with a web page/server that is doing this, in python to obtain the final post request's returned content?

In web scraping, you are doing a reverse process to get the data.
That means you don't follow the requests from the beginning, you must follow them from the endpoint.

Remember, you are working against a back-end developer trying to
prevent you from scraping the data.

How to do that?

Follow the results (data) you aim to get from the scraping.
Search for the results in the traffic, get the request responsible for loading it, and move backward step-by-step to understand what happened to get the data.


for example:
The link you are trying to scrap is loading the results in POST
request not GET.


Simulate the POST request and start from there.


Also don't forget to check the cookies, to see if it's mandatory to
get the results or optional.

